# Get the sum of the five most popular names every year | Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to get the sum of the five most popular names by every year and by gender from Google Cloud Database.
My data source is `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013` where we can see columns like: state,  gender, year, name and number.

My current code working, but the results seem not to be real.

```
SELECT count(x.number) as numberOfNames,
         x.name, 
         x.year
    FROM bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013 x
    JOIN (SELECT gender, year, name, SUM(number) as numbers
        FROM bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013
        WHERE gender='F'
        GROUP BY year, gender, name
        ORDER BY numbers DESC
        LIMIT 5
) y ON y.name = x.name
WHERE x.gender = 'F' 
GROUP BY x.name, x.year
```

Expected result is like:

```
Linda 60000 1910
Elizabeth 59000 1910
Jennifer 58000 1910
Mary 57000 1910
Patricia 56000 1910

Elizabeth 62000 1911
Jennifer 58000 1911
Linda 57500 1911
Mary 57000 1911
Patricia 56000 1911
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM (SELECT gender, name, year, SUM(number) as number,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY gender, year ORDER BY SUM(number) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013 n
      WHERE gender = 'F'
      GROUP BY gender, name, year
     ) n
WHERE seqnum <= 5;
```

Comment: I think it should be the sum of names from every state, your code is good, but it getting the biggest one from the only one state.

Comment: @Urken . . . I already fixed that before you made your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
with data as (
    select year, name, sum(number) as name_count
    FROM bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013
    where gender = 'F'
    group by 1,2
),
ordered as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by year order by name_count desc) as yearly_rank
    from data
)
select * from ordered
where yearly_rank <= 5
order by year, name_count desc
```